# Laravel query asserting against wrong value specified

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a very frustrating scenario, where I want to get all results where type = 2. Upon viewing this query in the view, it's showing `where type = 5`.

**Eloquent function:**

```
RequestModel::where('id', $object->pluck('id'))
    ->appointments()
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
    ->paginate('10');
```

**Appointments scope:**

```
public function scopeAppointments($query)
{
    return $query->where('type', '=', 2);
}
```

**Snippet of query outputted on view:**

```
from `requests` where `id` = '4' and `type` = '5'
```

If I remove the `->appointments()` method, it removes the `type = '5'`, so I know it's directly relating to it.

Even if I do not use a scope, and use a `->where('type', 2)`, it still returns `5`.

If I put the type query directly into the first section, it works as expected, for example:

```
RequestModel::where('type', 2)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
    ->paginate('10');
```

Why doesn't a second `where` query do as it's intended and why is it showing `5`, when I explicitly have chosen `2`!

Comment: Can you provide more details on your database structure?

Comment: try to change the value of 'id' and see if it is still 5 or something else.

Comment: You assumptions and logic seems correct, my initial thoughts is composer dump-autoload could help, because you are maybe running old compiled code.

Comment: Also try to change return `$query->where('type', '=', 2);` to `$query->where('type', 2);` or `$query->where('type', '2');` to see if that maybe helps. By all information you written it should work, so it's a bit confusing situation.

Comment: No clue as in why the value is replaced in the where clause, nor do I have any idea how your table is structured. But I've seen some issues with strict types in the queries, you could try a `->whereLoose('type', 5);`.

Comment: Dumb question, but is in variable `$query` and does it append the where clause correctly.

Comment: @MartinHenriksen, I tried a `composer dumpautoload` and it still shows the same issue. If I change the value to any integer, it still returns 5. `whereLoose` throws an error in the code too.

Comment: I think a route problem or use of variables before the code we see is the reason, one think we do at my office is to dd() some places to see if the code actually is running where you expect it to be